# Can I reliably determine if the last reboot was due to a kernel panic

Tags: linux, syslog, crash, kernel-panic

I have an embedded Linux system which I would like to reboot automatically in case it encounters a Kernel Panic. However, is there a way I can reliably determine on boot-time whether the last reboot was due to a kernel panic or was a clean reboot?

It seems that I cannot rely on `syslogs` or `kern.log` specifically because when I deliberately trigger a kernel panic using:

`echo c > /proc/sysrq-triger`

On the next boot, neither the `syslogs` or the `kern.log.*` have any dump of kernel panic in them.

I also looked at maybe reading the output of `last -x` to get a hint of last reboot was not clean, but it will show a `crash` only if the `pts` login sessions were not terminated cleanly. Since the embedded system doesn't have manual interaction using ssh or serial when its running and no user is logged in, I can't rely on that as well.

Also Note: The Embedded BSP I use does not support `ramoops-pstore`, so that's also not an option for me.

Comment: You can try to set up and look for a Kernel Core Dump: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kdump_(Linux)

Comment: Or this might be more helpful: https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-GA/html/SLES-all/cha-tuning-kexec.html

Comment: which init system does it use?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I think its the SYSV Init. The /sbin/init is a symbolic link to /lib/systemd/systemd binary. `file` on this binary shows the following: `/lib/systemd/systemd: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=18ce50ef03a7482735416b991ab1dd7a5fc93997, stripped`

Answer (score 1):

After a kernel panic no information is written to the logs, since the kernel is not working reliably (it could have a corrupt filesystem structure and writing to disk would make things worse).

So, instead of checking for a kernel panic entry in the logs, you could go the other way around, and add code to write a message to the logs whenever you do a clean shutdown or restart. The place to add that code depends on the init system you are using.

Then, at boot, you can check for that message. If you find it right before the entries associated to the current boot, then you know the shutdown/reboot was not due to a kernel panic, if it is not there a kernel panic occurred (or power loss).

Comment: Yeah I think having a service to monitor graceful shutdowns/crashes will be the way to go, and yes agreed that I can't be sure however to determine if the last crash was due to a kernel panic or power loss. Thanks for the input.